# Curl usage in Solr

Tags: json, csv, curl, solr, full-text-search

I am new in Solr. I am trying to submit some files including XML, CSV, JSON and txt. There is no problem when I submit XML files. However, I can't submit the others. Here is the error I see: Unsupported ContentType: application/vnd.ms-excel Not in: [application/xml, application/csv, application/json, text/json, text/csv, text/xml, application/javabin]

**Here is the question:** People suggested me to use *curl* but I don't know how can I get curl. Curl is not mandatory if there is any other way to submit. I need your suggestions.

You can see the errors: [ibb.co/k8Vphk](http://ibb.co/k8Vphk) and [ibb.co/ig7D8Q](http://ibb.co/ig7D8Q)

// I am using Windows //

Comment: You seem to be uploading a Microsoft Excel file. That's not supported. Try to export that into a CSV file and then submit that.

Comment: It is not Microsoft Excel file but even if it is Excel file, I can't submit json or txt files too. But there is no problem with XML files.

Comment: You can see the errors:   

https://ibb.co/k8Vphk     and     https://ibb.co/ig7D8Q